# How can i use hibernate reverse engineering tools to generate pojo with ejb3 annotation?

Tags: java, hibernate, ejb, reverse-engineering, pojo

[image]

When i use hibernate reverse engineering and select the user template with it, it doesn't work, still generate the pojo with `*.hbm.xml`.
I don't know has someone else used it before??

I tried many time and also use abstract classes but it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BzHksEXwTbfWOWpfbm05YjYzVFk/edit?usp=sharing)!
this will helps you

Comment: Include the actual answer in your answer please. The document might not be available some time in the future!